# Spring load properties file programmatically

Tags: java, spring

This is how I load application.properties if the file is on the classpath.

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MyApplication {
    // Have some public methods
}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyApplication.class);
        MyApplication app = context.getBean(MyApplication.class);

        // execute methods in app

    }
}
```

We are trying to deploy the application where the properties file is stored externally on a Google Cloud bucket (GCS). I can load the properties file from GCS and save it in memory. How do I pass the properties to the Application context and override the properties loaded from the classpath?

If it matters, it's a standalone app, not Spring Boot.

Comment: have you had any luck with below solution?

Comment: @GovindaSakhare Thanks. I am going to try today

Answer (score 1):

If you have it in memory then it should not be a problem. Get rid of `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` annotation and register `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean manually.

```
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    properties.setLocation([any implementation of Resource interface - use most applicable out of available or implement it by yourself]);
    return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read external properties file following way.

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "${external.properties}", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
```

When you run the `jar` file, pass external.properties filepath following way

```
java -Dexternal.properties=file:/path_to_properties my-service.jar
```